# Gitlab Push rules reject regex commit

Tags: regex, ruby, git, gitlab, re2

In Gitlab Push rules in "Require expression in commit messages" there is a regular expression:

```
^(feat|fix|perf|refactor|removed)(:\s)(HPA-\d+)(\s)(.+)
```

But when pushing a valid commit "feat: HPA-1234 Test" the commit is rejected.

When checked against regex101, the commit succeeds: https://regex101.com/r/hwwO1l/1

If we make a wider regular expression

```
^(feat|fix|perf|refactor|removed)(.*)
```

The commit is also rejected.

And if you explicitly specify a commit in the Push rules "feat: WPPA-3135 Test test" and try to push this commit, then the commit will also be rejected.

How can I check for what reason the commit does not pass the regular schedule?

Comment: The regex you shared is both RE2 and Onigmo compliant, so the problem is not with this regex. Maybe you could check with `\A` instead of `^` (this is for RoR though, everywhere else `^` is fine.)

Comment: With `\A` also rejected.

Comment: Then the problem is out there, not related to this regex.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact error and debug logging, this may help us

Comment: It looks like you can have it either reject on match, or pass on match, https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/push_rules.html#validate-commit-messages.  Possibly you have it set to reject on match?

Answer (score -2):

It happened to us that we made multiple commits on that branch and with one of the commits the submit message did not match the required regex. It seems that all commits on a branch have to match the regex which is set in Gitlab.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!